Help with Flow Measurement and Connectivity Technologies for Smart Cities Projects
I am involved in a project to install smart water meters in a city, as part of a smart city initiative. I am looking for detailed information on the following areas and would like your help:
Flow Measurement Technologies:
Direct: What are the best commercial instruments for measuring water flow (volumetric or mass) directly? If possible, include examples of brands and models that are highly recommended.
Indirect: Are there technologies or instruments that measure flow indirectly? What are the pros and cons of these technologies?
Cloud Connectivity:
What are the best methods and technologies for transmitting meter data to the cloud? Any recommendations for communication modules, protocols, or platforms that can guarantee efficient and secure integration?

Is there a question here or are you just looking for random ideas that might give you an idea where to look?

This is so broad it's like you want us to do the project for you. Do some research and come back with detailed questions.

It's an activity, it doesn't need to be so in-depth. It's more to get an idea of ​​the technologies used.
